# Como faço para estilizar somente um fillText no Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Estou implementando um sistema que gere um arquivo .gif com a assinatura de email do cliente, com as propriedades: nome, setor, telefone, ramal e email. O único problema até o momento é estilizar cada propriedade separadamente. A propriedade nome tem uma fonte e tamanho diferente da propriedade setor por exemplo. Quais dicas vocês me dão para estilizar cada propriedade? Agradeço desde já !

### index.html

```js
    var form = $('#oi');

        var nome = form.find('input[name="nome"]').val();

        $(document).ready(function(){
          var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          var imageObj = new Image();
          imageObj.onload = function(){
             context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
             context.font = "20px Arial bold";
             context.fillStyle = '#006400';
             imageObj.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
             context.fillText(nome, 243, 65);
             context.fillText("Estagiário de Desenvolvimento", 243, 85);
             context.fillText("(85) 000-000", 240, 125);
             context.fillText("|", 380, 125);
             context.fillText("Ramal", 390,125 );
             context.fillText("moises@edu.br", 243, 145);

         };
         imageObj.src = "ASSINATURA-BG.png"; 
        });
```

Comment: Você quer resposta em Jquery ou JavaScript puro?

Comment: Pode ser em jquery !

Comment: Você quer código limpo e funcional? Deixa estilo para cada um.

Answer (score 0):

Eae, beleza?

Bom, vc pode criar uma função de renderização limpa e chama-la passando os estilos que você deseja

Para complementar, criar um objeto com os styles das fontes e apenas chama-las para cada categoria (nome, setor, etc)